# How to access Azure Active Directory?

Tags: azure, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory, adal

I'd working on creating a ASP.NET 5 web application and would like to use ASP.NET Identity to manage users. I'd also like to use Azure Active Directory in a multi-tenant configuration. As I understand more about claims, I expect we will eventually create our own custom claims as well.

I see ASP.NET Identity can configure providers (Facebook, Google) but is it possible to set up Azure Active Directory to authenticate with Facebook / Google and have it flow through ASP.NET Identity? My *guess* is that flowing through Azure Active Directory would make our subsequent migration to claims authentication easier.

If so, any pointers to setting this up and road bumps that may be expected would be appreciated.

Regards,
Rajesh

Comment: Please take a look at Azure AD B2C: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-overview/.

Comment: That seems like it'll do exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic Azure Ad does not integrate directly with Facebook or Google, however the new B2C offer does. See http://aka.ms/aadb2c

Comment: Perfect. Working to integrate / implement now.